# SJMS2 vs JMS components for transfer messages from and to ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-artemis

I am trying to find the fastest way using Camel to transfer messages from one ActiveMQ  Artemis queue to another. I thought that Camel's [SJMS2](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/sjms2-component.html) component would be faster than Camel's traditional [JMS](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html) component, but routing with the JMS component is 2.5 times faster (20,000 vs 8,000 msg/s). I use Camel version 2.20.2 and Artemis version 2.11.0.

Route with JMS

```java
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class JMSTransferTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    @Test
    public void testArtemis() throws Exception {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(100);
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("jms://TEST.IN?connectionFactory=#artemisCF&concurrentConsumers=200")
                        .to("jms://TEST.OUT?connectionFactory=#artemisCF");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected JndiRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
        JndiRegistry registry = super.createRegistry();

        final ConnectionFactory connFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61622");
        final ConnectionFactory connFactoryDeadLeatter = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61622");
        JmsPoolConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new JmsPoolConnectionFactory();

        pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(connFactory);
        pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(20);
        pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxSessionsPerConnection(100);
        registry.bind("artemisCF", pooledConnectionFactory);
        registry.bind("deadLetterCF", connFactoryDeadLeatter);
        return registry;
    }
}
```

Route with SJMS2, other settings as in the code above

```java
@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("sjms2://TEST.IN?connectionFactory=#artemisCF&consumerCount=200&asyncStartListener=true")
                    .to("sjms2://TEST.OUT?connectionFactory=#artemisCF");
        }
    };
}
```

How can I use the SJMS2 component to get the same speeds as JMS component?

Comment: Have you run both routes using a profiler to see where the most time is being taken?

Comment: No, I haven't used it yet. Can I ask for a link where can I read more?

Comment: There are lots of Java profilers available. [This article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers) does a good job summarizing the options.

Comment: Thanks, I will read and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claus Ibsen replied on the mailing list as follows

> 200 consumers is too much. That instead makes it slower as you have
>   200 consumers racing for messages. Instead try to find a lower balance
>   that is closer to cpu cores etc.
>
> Also often a JMS client has a prefetch buffer (or some concept like
>   this) which means a consumer may pre-download 1000 messages and then
>   the other 199 consumers cant process these messages. So you need to
>   tweak this option too.
>
> Also if you have too many consumers and remote network connections
>   then you get too chatty over IO etc. So its all about tuning depending
>   on use-cases.
>
> spring-jms has a thread pool built in that can automatic grow/shrink
>   depending on load, and this can explain why its out of the box without
>   tuning can appear to be faster.
>
> Writing such logic is a bit more complex and this hasnt been added to
>   sjms. I created a ticket about this
>   https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14637
>
> You can get in touch with commercial Camel supports as there are
>   companies and consultants that has great experience with JMS brokers
>   and Camel and to get them tuned to very high performance. The settings
>   for JVM and OS and hardware can all make a big difference.

And I also found a good article on this topic https://dzone.com/articles/performance-tuning-ideas-for-apache-camel

Comment: If this is indeed the correct answer you should mark it as such to help others who run into this same issue in the future.